# How to get path of file in war file in java

Tags: java

i have a .html file in war file and war file is in

```
D:/foldername/jboss/server/default/deploy/sampleproject.war
```

How to retrieve this path. Please help me on this.

Comment: In future Servlet API related questions, please do not use [java] tag, use [servlets] instead. See also my comment on your other question on this subject.

Comment: @BalusC  Here i need to get path war file that is present in server.But what you have redirected to question that wont fetch path ,anything like that.

Comment: @BalusC  Can you show me how to get path of war file in server

Comment: It shows how to get a resource (as input stream) from webcontent. You should not be interested in the absolute path at all as that's not portable (this is also explained and linked in the duplicate).

Comment: @BalusC i need to get pathname of a file in web Container.I am trying with this code but it shows error for   getServletContext() and tells to create method for it.getServletContext().getRealPath("/filepathInContext").How could i create method for it.

Comment: Put/call the code in a normal servlet class. And, please DO NOT use `getRealPath()`. This is recipe for disaster. Again, carefully read the duplicate how to properly access resources in a WAR.

Comment: @BalusC I need to get context path without depending on servlets,as i need to get path of context in method of bussiness layes,is there any way i could get.even if it is through xml file is okay.Please help me on this.